# How do I stop the parent if child or worker goes in exception in multi-processing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to achieve 2 things:
1) Keep the parent alive until the child/worker completes and
2) If a child/worker goes into an exception, then the parent should stop after that exception. It should not run the remaining workers after the exception.

I have written a code but am unable to get what I am looking for.

```py
def waitTime(ds, index):
    try:
        if index == 3:
            index = 15
        ds[index] = 'WORKED!!!'
    except:
        global isException
        isException = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    isException = False
    ds = multiprocessing.Manager().list([None]*5)
    new = []
    for i in range(1, len(ds)+1):
        temp = multiprocessing.Process(target=waitTime, args=(ds, i-1))
        new.append(temp)
        temp.start()
        temp.join()
        if isException:
            break

    print(ds)
```

my expected results are: ['WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', None, None]

My actual results are: ['WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.  First, you do not actually raise an exception so your exception clause in your worker is never triggered.  Second, global variables do not travel between processes - you need another manager for that.

Consider this:

```
def waitTime(ds, isException, index):
    try:
        if index == 3:
            index = 15
            raise IndexError
        ds[index] = 'WORKED!!!'
    except IndexError:
        isException.value = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    isException = multiprocessing.Manager().Value("h", 0)
    ds = multiprocessing.Manager().list([None]*5)
    new = []
    for i in range(1, len(ds)+1):
        temp = multiprocessing.Process(target=waitTime, args=(ds, isException, i-1))
        new.append(temp)
        temp.start()
        temp.join()
        if isException.value == 1:
            break

    print(ds)
```

Now we raise an IndexError and catch that. Your `isException` is now another manager used to carry the value between your processes.   It is not necessarily very elegant but it works.

Comment: I think it should be noted that while this (like the OP's code) is using multiple processes, very little concurrent processing actually occurs.

Comment: Indeed. As it is now written, it would be better to remove multiprocessing completely and the result would be exactly the same. I assume this is a stub to highlight an issue or school work where the task is to do something utterly pointless to demonstrate knowledge of multiprocessing.

Comment: In a more realistic scenario using [`Pool.map_sync()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=map_async#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async), exceptions could be propagated between processes by using the optional _`error_callback`_ function.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable not shared among multiprocess but in thread.You have to use Value,Queue, Lock provided by multiprocessing module.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Value

v = Value('i', 0) # where i means integer type, 0 is default value


def waitTime(ds, index):
    try:
        if index == 3:
            index = 15
        ds[index] = 'WORKED!!!'
    except:
        v.value = 1 # v.value to assign integer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    isException = False
    ds = multiprocessing.Manager().list([None] * 5)
    new = []
    for i in range(1, len(ds) + 1):

       temp = multiprocessing.Process(target=waitTime, args=(ds, i - 1))
       new.append(temp)
       temp.start()
       temp.join()
       if v.value == 1:
           v.value = 0
           break

output:
['WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', 'WORKED!!!', None, None]
```